# Angular2 Hot to get all parameters from url?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I currently try to get nice routes in my application but in my current implementation I have to get and check all parameters in my route subscription. Is there any way I can get a 'static' parameter as `employees` or `departments` from the route that I can make a difference earlier instead of checking all parameter values for every possibility?
I am also open for improvements if any of my routes is unlogical or just wrong.

```
export const EmployeeManagementRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{
path: 'employee-management',
component: EmployeeManagementComponent,
children: [
  //display all employees
  { 
    path: '', 
    //is there any way to make this redirict relative to the component the router is for?
    redirectTo: '/employee-management/employees/department/all',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  //display all employees from a specific department
  { 
    path: 'employees//department/:department',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  //open dialog for deleting or creating a new employee or    
  if option is 'show' and id is not undefined show a specific employee 
  { 
    path: 'employees/action/:option/:id',   
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  //display all departments
  { 
    path: 'departments',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  //open dialog for deleting or creating a new department
  { 
    path: 'departments/action/:option',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },

]
}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ActivatedRoute`. It is not only for getting params. Something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
     let path = this.route.url.value.map(val => val.path);
    }
```

will give you the parts of the url as a string array. For instance `["employees","department","management"].`

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Parse your url like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export class TopNavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    let parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
    console.log(parsedUrl);  
  }
}
```

In the received object the parsed url is located under:
root->children->primary->segments

You can read more right [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)